# SearchView doesn't show icon in ActionBar with SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW and SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM

Tags: java, android, android-appcompat

The Android [SearchView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html) icon won't show up in the ActionBar, instead, if there is room, the word 'SEARCH' will be displayed instead.

How we're using it:

```
public static MenuItem addSearchItem(Menu menu, SearchView searchView) {
    MenuItem item = menu.add(Menu.NONE, R.id.search_item, Menu.NONE, R.string.search_label);
    MenuItemCompat.setShowAsAction(item, MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_COLLAPSE_ACTION_VIEW | MenuItemCompat.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    MenuItemCompat.setActionView(item, searchView);
    ...
}
```

Called like so:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    if (itemsLoaded) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.new_episodes, menu);

        final SearchView sv = new SearchView(getActivity());
        MenuItemUtils.addSearchItem(menu, sv);
```

[image: SEARCH word being displayed instead of icon]

If, however, we just use SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM, then we'll get the icon, but the SearchView won't work if the search was collapsed in to the menu.

Any ideas about why this might be?

**UPDATE**

This behavior occurs even if the SearchView is defined within the menu xml.  **It seems to only behave properly if you don't specify 'collapseActionView'**.

The layout:

```
    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          android:icon="?attr/searchIcon"
          android:title="@string/search_label"
          custom:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
          custom:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
```

The creation code:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    if (itemsLoaded) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.new_episodes, menu);

        final MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        final SearchView sv = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
        sv.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.search_hint));
        SearchViewCompat.setOnQueryTextListener(sv, new SearchViewCompat.OnQueryTextListenerCompat() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                sv.clearFocus();
                ((MainActivity) getActivity()).loadChildFragment(SearchFragment.newInstance(s));
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: What is 'searchView'?

Comment: Added a link. Android SearchView: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.html

Comment: That I know but what is 'searchView' object? how have you defined it? post code. And why dont you declare it in menu.xml?

Comment: More code posted.  I'm not sure why this wasn't declared in the menu. I'm not the original maintainer.  This was working fine until we wanted it to collapse in to the menu under some circumstances.  I'm going to investigate moving to the xml layout, but I'd prefer a simpler fix if possible.  Plus, it would just be nice to understand why this isn't working.

Comment: Now with code that uses menu xml for the layout, with the same result.

Comment: If you specify only 'collapseActionView' then? It should work.